# In Android, can't handle exception thrown from Use-case in Clean Architecture

Tags: exception, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I want to implement **Clean Architecture** in my recent app. But I faced some trouble of error handling in useCase. I can't handle exception thrown from Usecase class although other library based exceptions were successfully handled. It means, when any exception is thrown by Firebase, it is successfully handled and show the exception text in Toast. But when I throw any exception from Usecase class like

> Please fill both field

or

> Please give email

or

> Please give password

then app crashed. So how can I handled the exception of use case class and show the text in Toast?

Here is code I tried.

`FirebaseAuthRepository.kt`

```
interface FirebaseAuthRepository {
    suspend fun register(email: String, password: String): Flow<User>
}
```

`FirebaseAuthRepositoryImpl.kt`

```
class FirebaseAuthRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuthDataSource: FirebaseAuthDataSource,
    private val firebaseAuthMapper: FirebaseAuthMapper
) : FirebaseAuthRepository {

    override suspend fun register(email: String, password: String): Flow<User> {
        return flow {
            emit(firebaseAuthDataSource.register(email, password))
        }.map {
            firebaseAuthMapper.toUser(it)
        }
    }    
}
```

`FirebaseAuthDataSource.kt`

```
class FirebaseAuthDataSource @Inject constructor(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

    suspend fun register(email: String, password: String): FirebaseUser? {
        val authResult: AuthResult = firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
        return authResult.user
    }
}
```

`RegisterUseCase.kt`

```
class RegisterUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuthRepository: FirebaseAuthRepository
) {

    suspend fun execute(email: String, password: String): Flow<User> {
        if (email.trim().isEmpty() && password.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw Exception("Please fill both field")
        } else {
            if (email.trim().isEmpty()) throw Exception("Please give email")
            if (password.trim().isEmpty()) throw Exception("Please give password")
        }

        return firebaseAuthRepository.register(email, password)
    }

}
```

`LoginViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val registerUseCase: RegisterUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    val register: MutableStateFlow<Resource<User>> = MutableStateFlow(Loading(true))

    fun register(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            loginUseCase.execute(email, password)
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .onStart { }
                .onCompletion { register.value = Loading(false) }
                .catch { register.value = Error(it) }
                .collectLatest { register.value = Success(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

`Resource.kt`

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    data class Loading(val isLoading: Boolean) : Resource<Nothing>()
    data class Success<T>(val item: T) : Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

`RegistrationFragment.kt`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RegistrationFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentRegisterBinding>() {

    private val viewModel: RegistrationViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun getViewBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?
    ): FragmentRegisterBinding {
        return FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    }

    override fun configureViews() {
        binding?.registerButton?.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.register(
                binding?.mailEditText?.value() ?: "",
                binding?.passwordEditText?.value() ?: ""
            )
        }
    }

    override fun bindWithViewModel() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.registration.collectLatest {
                when(it) {
                    is Loading -> {
                        if (it.isLoading) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    is Success -> {
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.home_fragment)
                    }

                    is Error -> {
                        requireContext().toast(it.throwable.message ?: "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` handler like below (You can put it into BaseViewModel)

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    run {
        toast.value = exception.message
        exception.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(TAG, "Caught $exception")
    }
}
```

Then add `handler` into your viewModel where `viewModelScope.launch`

```
fun register(email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        loginUseCase.execute(email, password)
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
            .onStart { }
            .onCompletion { register.value = Loading(false) }
            .catch { register.value = Error(it) }
            .collectLatest { register.value = Success(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the issue. Thanks a lot [@Rifan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5756788/rifan) vai for answer. Here the code, I tried.

`BaseViewmodel.kt`

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun handleException(action: (Throwable)->Unit): CoroutineExceptionHandler {
        return CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            action(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

`LoginViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    val login: MutableStateFlow<Resource<User>> = MutableStateFlow(Loading(true))

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(handleException { login.value = Error(it) }) {
            loginUseCase.execute(email, password)
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .onCompletion { login.value = Loading(false) }
                .collectLatest { login.value = Success(it) }
        }
    }
}
```